# My app icon scales differently in two different folders

Tags: windows, visual-studio, icons, desktop

I created an icon (.ico) which includes the following sizes:
16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, 256x256

The original files that I used are png with transparency.
When I created the icon file, I imported the files
so that my icon editor also shows transparency for each 'page' of the icon.
The opaque area is in the center (a rectangle) with transparent areas above and below (to complete the square size format - kind of like Letterbox for movies)

I added the ico file to my project from Properties > Application > Icon and Manifest > Icon/browse.
It gets added to the project and is visible in the Solution Explorer and for its Properties, Build Action = Embedded Resource.

After I build my project, and look in the  'Project' > bin > debug folder, the icon appears correct for all views (Detail, Small Icon, Large Icon, etc.)
However, if I copy the exe to my desktop, the icon shows up scaled to eliminate the transparent areas thereby appearing in the wrong aspect.

When I look in the 'Project' > obj > debug folder, the icon appears scaled (like on the desktop) for all views.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - I simply used Build > Clean Solution
and the icons are correct now wherever I view them.